# Is there an offline mode in Cloud 9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

Where I work at this moment the internet keeps cutting out. Is there an offline mode in Cloud 9 IDE, with which I could cache/pre-download all of the source files in advance and if the network goes down temporarily I could keep working and later sync the changes when it is back again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an important use case. We don't offer this yet and are looking into adding the offline feature to our platform.

Comment: what happened to this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbZBuxBdT24
http://googlecode.blogspot.ro/2011/05/working-offline-with-cloud9-on-google.html
?